# Redirection user after login does not update address bar

Tags: angular, routes

I need to redirect user after login.So i set returnUrl in queryParams.But after login browser address bar is like "http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=%2Fhome". It does not redirect to home page.

I tried to set returnUrl and print to console to find out the bug.But can not find it.

Below is my authguard can activate function

```
 canActivate(route, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
return this.authService.isLoggedIn.take(1).map((isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    this.router.navigate(["/login"], {
      queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }
    }); // {4}
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
}
```

And here is my login function

```
  login() {
let credential = this.loginForm.value;
let self = this;
this.authService.authenticate(credential).subscribe(
  res => {
    if (res) {
      this.alertService.success("Logged In");
      let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get("returnUrl");
      if (returnUrl) {
        this.router.navigate([returnUrl]);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
      }
    } else {
      this.alertService.error("user or password is incorrect");
    }
  },
  error => {
    let log_error: LoginError = error;
    this.alertService.error(log_error.message);
   }
  );
}
```

Router should redirect to home page after successfully login.In my case user successfully logged in but he is not redirected to homepage.

Comment: If `returnUrl` is not set, does it correctly navigates to the home page?

Answer (score 0):

It’s obvious that the angular cannot parse state.url. Why don’t you use this.router.navigate (["/ homepage"]) that will send the user to the home page after the route guard?

Comment: I don't want to limit the user only to home page.let's think that i have url like "localhost:4200/customers".user enter it into the adress bar when he is not logged in.so after log in i want to redirect him to customers page.And angular can parse state.url cause i printed it to the console.And it shows "/home".

Comment: maybe the whole thing is that "/ home" is a slash? Try without it, maybe the problem is this. Cut it from the string